# Accordion not showing up in web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a little help function at the bottom of my screen to help users navigate my page, I just think it would be a nice sleak way to have a Accordian as a little drop down appear helper but I cannot get it to work at all.

I have followed [This](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible) tutorial as it is very simple but it does not work at all. it just displays the Lorem Ipsum as h3 tags.

I've got jquery-ui and jquery 3.1.1 installed using nuget.

I have removed all of the razer syntax as the issue does not concern all of the razer. I tested it without and the problem still persists

```
@model WAD_Tracker.Models.Weight

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create a new Weight Entry</h2>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                collapsible: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>



<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
    </div>
</div>


<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".date-picker").datepicker();
</script>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/jquery-ui.css")

}
```

Comment: Little confused about the problem here. If I copy/paste only `#accordion` and its contents, plus the little jQuery script you have (and include jQuery + jQuery UI) into a Stack Snippet, it works fine. What do you mean doesn't work at all? The accordions don't open and close when you click the headers, or some other problem?

Comment: @cjl750 it doesn't do the accordion effect, it just renders teh html as if i wasnt trying to do an accordion

Comment: Hard to say then. There could be some other JS from your page interfering, or maybe you need to check the actual rendered HTML and make sure it is coming out correctly. Or maybe you have some CSS that is causing problems by making all the accordion divs always appear open when otherwise the built-in jQuery UI styles would close them by default. If you can update your question with enough info to reproduce the problem, I can take a look.

Comment: @cjl750 the only real other way I see is you just download the GIT project as its a MVC project but I don't expect someone to go through that much effort.

Comment: What you can do is pull up an example webpage of this accordion from your project – whatever the rendered output is – and then strip out the HTML, CSS, JS that isn't related to the accordion and include only what's left over in your post. As long as what's left over reproduces the problem, hopefully someone can give you an answer, and then if you can't just copy/paste that straight into your code base you'll at least have something to work from to modify your actual templates. That's probably not a quick task for you to do, but that is honestly by design.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing it live, it's hard to be sure, but I suspect your issue is that you are initializing the datepicker before the page loading is complete, and so jQuery  hasn't finished loading yet.

Try putting the datepicker init in a $(document).ready function.